# Follow Up on Twitter using iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

Can User follow up on twitter using iphone application. I have done the functionality of sending tweet to twitter account. But now I have to do the follow up on twitter functionality.

I have an iphone application. I need to do the follow up on twitter functionality using the application in the info page. In which if user clicks on follow up on twitter then user need to enter username or password and then user can follow up on twitter to the selected application.

Please help me to find out the solution. If possible then give me some reference. Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) is a really good library for doing Twitter stuff on the iPhone. It comes with lots of examples on how to use it.

Comment: I have send tweet using MGTwitterEngine. But I need to follow up on twitter using iPhone.

Comment: That does work with MGTwitterEngine as well. See the included examples.

Comment: Can you give me the specific reference or example for the follow up on twitter functionality. I am really thankful if you help me for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Use MGTwitter Engine and invoke enableUpdatesFor method
     -(IBAction)Followme:(id)sender
      {
         NSString *username = @"Twitter_user_name";
         [_engine enableUpdatesFor:username];
      }
```